# String interpolation in node.js use back quotes with an existing string template

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var abc = "text";
var text = "content of text";
var out_right = ` ${abc}=${text}`;  // get string "text=content_of_text"

var out_template = '${abc}=${text}';
var out_wrong_0 = ` out_template `;
var out_wrong_1 = ` ${out_template} `;
```

My question is how to use string `out_template` to get the string I need: `"text=content_of_text"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backquote literals are compile-time things, there's no runtime facility to re-evaluate them. That means, you either have to resort to `eval`, as in

```js
var abc = "text";
var text = "content of text";
var out_template = '${abc}=${text}';
console.log(eval("`" + out_template + "`"));
```

or to use other templating techniques (util.format, mustache etc).

Comment: isn't using eval a [massive security hole](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!)?